# Framework7 vue components not showing up when I run in an emulator. Only the default Cordova page showing

Tags: javascript, android-studio, cordova, vue.js, html-framework-7

I am using framework7 with vue.js and Cordova to build a mobile app, but whenever I try to run the app in an emulator all I get is the default Cordova page with the icon, and none of my components from framework7 appear. I have no idea why it's doing this. the emulator is running android 9. These are some of the files.

index.html (I havent made any changes)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <!--
  Customize this policy to fit your own app's needs. For more guidance, see:
      https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist/blob/master/README.md#content-security-policy
  Some notes:
    * gap: is required only on iOS (when using UIWebView) and is needed for JS->native communication
    * https://ssl.gstatic.com is required only on Android and is needed for TalkBack to function properly
    * Disables use of inline scripts in order to mitigate risk of XSS vulnerabilities. To change this:
      * Enable inline JS: add 'unsafe-inline' to default-src
  -->
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data: gap: content:">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui, viewport-fit=cover">

  <meta name="theme-color" content="#007aff">
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
  <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
  <title>Easy Dine</title>




  <!-- built styles file will be auto injected -->
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
  <% if (process.env.TARGET === 'cordova') { %>
  <script src="cordova.js"></script>
  <% } %>
  <!-- built script files will be auto injected -->
</body>
</html>
```

app.vue (I havent made any changes)

```
<template>
<f7-app :params="f7params" >

  <!-- Left panel with cover effect-->
  <f7-panel left cover theme-dark>
    <f7-view>
      <f7-page>
        <f7-navbar title="Left Panel"></f7-navbar>
        <f7-block>
          <f7-button fill raised login-screen-open="#my-login-screen">Login Screen</f7-button>
        </f7-block>
      </f7-page>
    </f7-view>
  </f7-panel>


  <!-- Right panel with reveal effect-->
  <f7-panel right reveal theme-dark>
    <f7-view>
      <f7-page>
        <f7-navbar title="Right Panel"></f7-navbar>
        <f7-block>Right panel content goes here</f7-block>
      </f7-page>
    </f7-view>
  </f7-panel>


  <!-- Views/Tabs container -->
  <f7-views tabs class="safe-areas">
    <!-- Tabbar for switching views-tabs -->
    <f7-toolbar tabbar labels bottom>
      <f7-link tab-link="#view-home" tab-link-active icon-ios="f7:house_fill" icon-aurora="f7:house_fill" icon-md="material:home" text="Home"></f7-link>
      <f7-link tab-link="#view-catalog" icon-ios="f7:square_list_fill" icon-aurora="f7:square_list_fill" icon-md="material:view_list" text="Catalog"></f7-link>
      <f7-link tab-link="#view-settings" icon-ios="f7:gear" icon-aurora="f7:gear" icon-md="material:settings" text="Settings"></f7-link>
    </f7-toolbar>

    <!-- Your main view/tab, should have "view-main" class. It also has "tab-active" class -->
    <f7-view id="view-home" main tab tab-active url="/"></f7-view>

    <!-- Catalog View -->
    <f7-view id="view-catalog" name="catalog" tab url="/catalog/"></f7-view>

    <!-- Settings View -->
    <f7-view id="view-settings" name="settings" tab url="/settings/"></f7-view>

  </f7-views>


  <!-- Popup -->
  <f7-popup id="my-popup">
    <f7-view>
      <f7-page>
        <f7-navbar title="Popup">
          <f7-nav-right>
            <f7-link popup-close>Close</f7-link>
          </f7-nav-right>
        </f7-navbar>
        <f7-block>
          <p>Popup content goes here.</p>
        </f7-block>
      </f7-page>
    </f7-view>
  </f7-popup>

  <f7-login-screen id="my-login-screen">
    <f7-view>
      <f7-page login-screen>
        <f7-login-screen-title>Login</f7-login-screen-title>
        <f7-list form>
          <f7-list-input
            type="text"
            name="username"
            placeholder="Your username"
            :value="username"
            @input="username = $event.target.value"
          ></f7-list-input>
          <f7-list-input
            type="password"
            name="password"
            placeholder="Your password"
            :value="password"
            @input="password = $event.target.value"
          ></f7-list-input>
        </f7-list>
        <f7-list>
          <f7-list-button title="Sign In" login-screen-close @click="alertLoginData"></f7-list-button>
          <f7-block-footer>
            Some text about login information.<br>Click "Sign In" to close Login Screen
          </f7-block-footer>
        </f7-list>
      </f7-page>
    </f7-view>
  </f7-login-screen>
</f7-app>
</template>
<script>
  import cordovaApp from '../js/cordova-app.js';
  import routes from '../js/routes.js';

  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        // Framework7 Parameters
        f7params: {
          id: 'io.framework7.myapp', // App bundle ID
          name: 'Easy Dine', // App name
          theme: 'auto', // Automatic theme detection
          // App root data
          data: function () {
            return {

              // Demo products for Catalog section
              products: [
                {
                  id: '1',
                  title: 'Apple iPhone 8',
                  description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi tempora similique reiciendis, error nesciunt vero, blanditiis pariatur dolor, minima sed sapiente rerum, dolorem corrupti hic modi praesentium unde saepe perspiciatis.'
                },
                {
                  id: '2',
                  title: 'Apple iPhone 8 Plus',
                  description: 'Velit odit autem modi saepe ratione totam minus, aperiam, labore quia provident temporibus quasi est ut aliquid blanditiis beatae suscipit odio vel! Nostrum porro sunt sint eveniet maiores, dolorem itaque!'
                },
                {
                  id: '3',
                  title: 'Apple iPhone X',
                  description: 'Expedita sequi perferendis quod illum pariatur aliquam, alias laboriosam! Vero blanditiis placeat, mollitia necessitatibus reprehenderit. Labore dolores amet quos, accusamus earum asperiores officiis assumenda optio architecto quia neque, quae eum.'
                },
              ]
            };
          },

          // App routes
          routes: routes,


          // Input settings
          input: {
            scrollIntoViewOnFocus: this.$device.cordova && !this.$device.electron,
            scrollIntoViewCentered: this.$device.cordova && !this.$device.electron,
          },
          // Cordova Statusbar settings
          statusbar: {
            iosOverlaysWebView: true,
            androidOverlaysWebView: false,
          },
        },

        // Login screen data
        username: '',
        password: '',
      }
    },
    methods: {
      alertLoginData() {
        this.$f7.dialog.alert('Username: ' + this.username + '<br>Password: ' + this.password);
      }
    },
    mounted() {
      this.$f7ready((f7) => {
        // Init cordova APIs (see cordova-app.js)
        if (f7.device.cordova) {
          cordovaApp.init(f7);
        }
        // Call F7 APIs here
      });
    }
  }
</script>
```

catalog.vue (the only file i've changed)

```
<template>
  <f7-page name="catalog">
    <f7-navbar title="Catalog"></f7-navbar>
    <f7-block strong inset>
          <f7-button @click="scanCode" fill raised >Scan New Code</f7-button>
    </f7-block>
  </f7-page>
</template>
<script>
//var QRScanner = require('QRScanner');

  export default {
    data() { 
      return {

      };
    },
    methods: {
      scanCode(){
        cordova.plugins.qrscanner.prepare(onDone);
        cordova.plugins.qrscanner.scan(displayContents);
        cordova.plugins.qrscanner.show();
      },

      onDone(err, status){
        if(err) {
          alert("Error Occured");
        }
        if(status.authorized){
          alert("you may use the camera");

        }
        else if(status.denied){
          alert("you dont have acces to the camera");
        }
        else{
          alert("something");
        }
      },

      displayContents(err, text){
        if(err){
          alert("error displaying contents")
        }else {

          alert(text);
        }
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

here's an image of what I get on the  emulator
[image]

here's an image of what is supposed to show
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked after I ran the command

```
npm run build-prod-cordova-android
```